# MYSQL - How to avoid duplicate value based on unique key and servertimestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to update duplicate value with 0 if the two unique column's serverTimeStamp is between 15 second difference.

```
id  D_Id             value serverTimeStamp
1   001               1    2016-10-05 23:37:02
2   002               1    2016-10-05 23:37:04
3   001               1    2016-10-05 23:52:24
4   002               1    2016-10-05 23:55:24
5   001               1    2016-10-06 00:29:09
6   002               1    2016-10-06 00:29:11
7   002               1    2016-10-06 01:56:51
8   001               1    2016-10-06 01:56:58
```

Expecting output :

```
id  D_Id             value serverTimeStamp
1   001               1    2016-10-05 23:37:02
2   002               0    2016-10-05 23:37:04
3   001               1    2016-10-05 23:52:24
4   002               1    2016-10-05 23:55:24
5   001               1    2016-10-06 00:29:09
6   002               0    2016-10-06 00:29:11
7   002               1    2016-10-06 01:56:51
8   001               0    2016-10-06 01:56:58
```

how to achieve this by query?

Comment: interesting 2nd col name

Comment: A "group" in the context of your desired query is actually a cluster of records all of which are within 15 seconds of each other.  Hence, I think this is a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: The problem is not well defined. The dupes can effect ones that follow. It potentially cascades. Also it is a patch. What to do with new inserts, such as enforcement in a trigger, moving forward.

Comment: That awkward situation when the `unique column` is not `unique` at all. By the way, do you want to update your table by your expected output?

Comment: @Drew It's well defined if the query to identify target records is part of the update statement.  There's a unique id column, but this would be a real headache.  I think even Gordon might not attempt it.

Comment: what unique column id? Where is the rule in the technical requirements for how a turned-zero impacts or doesn't the 15 second window? Nebulous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
UPDATE your_table YT
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    id,
    D_Id,
    value,
    serverTimeStamp,
    @prevTimeStamp AS prevTimeStamp,
    @prevTimeStamp := serverTimeStamp
    FROM your_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevTimeStamp := NULL) AS var
    ORDER BY serverTimeStamp
) AS x 
ON YT.id = x.id
SET YT.value = 0
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,x.prevTimeStamp,YT.serverTimeStamp) <= 15;
```

---

Sort the records based on ascending order of time.

Store the previous row's serverTimeStamp value in a user defined variable.

Now make an inner join between your table and the above sorted table (with previous row's timestamp).

And finally update the `value` to zero (`0`) of those records only whose `previousTimeStamp` is within `15` seconds of `serverTimeStamp`

Comment: Unknown column 'YT.prevTimeStamp' in 'where clause.